# External file number update

Tags: html, text, dynamic, view, count

I am having a hard time even searching for what I want let alone figuring out how to do it.
What I want to do is to update a number one a webpage from a separate file.  For example on the main web page there will be a number that is being referenced from an external wither a text file or something else. That way I can just update the text file without having to edit the main code.

Things I have tried

- object data="/path_to_text_file/text.txt" type="text/plain
  embed src="stuff.txt"

things like that.

This would definitely be a work around for my ideal situation.  Ideally I am trying to have a google maps photo on the page with a live view count to go along with it.
Scraping would be my next guess but I am unsure.